# Distance between signals / rows for each levels in R

Tags: r, rows, distance

I have the following sample:

```
Id = c(1, 1,3,3,3)
long =  c("60.466681", "60.664116", "60.766690", "60.86879", "60.986569" )
lat = c("24.158253", "24.266036", "24.368283", "24.479058", "24.5599858")
data = data.frame(Id, long, lat)  
data$long <- as.numeric(as.character(data$long))
data$lat <- as.numeric(as.character(data$lat))
data$Id <- as.factor(data$Id)
```

I would like to create a new column called `distance` that is the cumulative sum of distance between each lat/long points for each level of the factor `Id`

I tried to create my own function with what I found on internet and using distCosine() from the package `geosphere`. I finally got:

## create the function

```
 distance <- Vectorize(function(i, j) distCosine(data[i,], data[j,]))
```

## run the function

```
  library(dplyr)
Dist <- data %>%
  filter(Id != 0) %>%  #I keep this because in my final data I can have Id==0
  group_by(Id) %>%
  do(distance(.$lat, .$long))
```

It looks that the function does not work, I guess there is a problem with the loop to go to the next row.

What could be wrong?

Comment: In the [documentation](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/geosphere/docs/distCosine) for the function distCosine, it says p1 and p2 "Can be a vector of two numbers, a matrix of 2 columns (first one is longitude, second is latitude) or a SpatialPoints* object". You're supplying two vectors of coordinates instead.

Additionally, with dplyr, you can just do:
`Dist <- data %>%
  filter(Id != 0) %>% 
  group_by(Id) %>%
  summarize(dist = distance(lat,long))`

once you fix your function.

Comment: Thank you @shreyasgm. Here is what I did: the function is now `distance <- Vectorize(function(i, j) distCosine(data[i,c("lat", "long")], data[j,c("lat", "long")]))` and the final line with `plyr ` is `Dist <- data %>% filter(Id != 0) %>% group_by(Id) %>% summarize(dist = distance(lat,long))`.
` bit I have the error `Error: expecting a single value
Error during wrapup: cannot open the connection`

Answer (score 4):

You could try:

```
data %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  mutate(longlead = lead(long), latlead = lead(lat)) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(dist = distCosine(c(long,lat), c(longlead, latlead)))
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [3 x 6]
#Groups: <by row>
#
#      Id     long      lat longlead  latlead     dist
#  (fctr)    (dbl)    (dbl)    (dbl)    (dbl)    (dbl)
#1      1 60.46668 24.15825 60.66412 24.26604 23361.55
#2      3 60.76669 24.36828 60.86879 24.47906 16098.39
#3      3 60.86879 24.47906 60.98657 24.55999 14948.38
```

The idea here is to create two new columns (`longlead` and `latlead`) using `lead()`, filter out the `NA` values (as they are the last entry in a group and therefore, have no subsequent values to compute the distance against) and then perform a row-wise operation with `distCosine()`

Comment: Instead of using `rowwise`, I think you could use `distCosine(cbind(long,lat),cbind(longlead,latlead))`.

Also, I might have this wrong, but there are 3 points with Id = 3. That means that there should be 3 combinations of points for which distances are calculated for the Id 3, right?

Comment: @shreyasgm The way I understand the question, OP wants to have the distance between a point in a group and the subsequent one (next row), if there are *3* points in `Id 3` then you have: (point1, point2), (point2, point3), (point3, NA) (there is no "point 4" to compute against). Hence, only 2 results for 3 points. The way I understood it, you always have n-1 results (n being the group size).

Comment: Thanks, @Steven. I thought there would be an additional (point3,point1), but I think your interpretation could be valid too.

Answer (score -1):

I find it easier to just use the following command without pipes:

```
Test <- mutate(DIST = distHaversine(c(LONG_DEB, LAT_DEB), c(LONG_FIN, LAT_FIN)), rowwise(Test))
```